# Get copy of the code

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I create a form using Cognito Forms and then get the source code?

I do not want to house the data on Cognito's servers and would like to be able to control where my data goes.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: Please note that this is not the official support site for Cognito Forms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We do not provide the source code for Cognito Forms. Though you can make and embed your forms and can have the entry data sent out to your own database via webhooks, the data will still be stored in Cognito Forms.

You can learn more about our Data Security in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/74/entries/data-security), or ask us direct question by submitting a [Support Ticket](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/).